# How to group by on multiple keys

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am learning kafka stream and kafka table. I am trying to `groupby` on multiple keys like below

I have a topic - `httpresponse` which contains `json` records like

```
{ "syncId" : "1233",
  "status" : "200",
  "url" : "http://xy.co.com"
}
{ "syncId" : "1233",
  "status" : "500",
  "url" : "http://xyz/table.co.com"
}
{ "syncId" : "1233",
  "status" : "200",
  "url" : "http://xy.co.com"
}
{ "syncId" : "4566",
  "status" : "200",
  "url" : "http://xy.co.com"
}
```

Now I want to persistent the data may be in `ktable` like below

```
syncId , status, count 
1233,     200 ,   2
1233,     500,    1
4566,     200,    1
```

As far as I have understand, I can do groupby key `syncId` but it will give me count of `1233` as `3` and `4566` to `1` which I do not want.

Can you please help me how can I do this.

Comment: A KTable cannot have multiple columns

Answer (score 0):

Create composite string keys with some delimiter, using map operator, then group by those

```
id_status, count
1233;200,   2
1233;500,    1
4566;200,    1
```